# ABAP editor retrieve old code after activating it, aka Ctrl + Z

Tags: abap

I've mistakenly replaced the whole code of a program (selected all and pasted the code of another program) and then activated it. Unfortunately Ctrl+Z doesn't work after a program is activated. Is there a way to retrieve the original code of the program?

Please note that this program hasn't been transported yet, so I cannot use Utilities -> Version -> Version management

Comment: I think you lost your code. For the future: You can always create temporary versions during your developments,

Comment: Was this done in a development system? If so, unfortunately the code is lost.

Comment: @knut please convert your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: You can always restore it from the system backup. The backups of your dev system are done on a daily basis, aren't they?

Comment: Was this program modified and stored in an already released transport before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you lost your code.

If there was no transport before, then you have no history.

For the future: You can always create temporary versions during your developments. I recommend to create a temporary version before you do any critical action. This temporary versions are listed in Utilities -> Version -> Version management until you release your transport.